# How to convert Mesh to Object3D

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm using `Typescript` with `Webpack`. And for creating a 3D floor in `three.js` I used several plane objects (100 in 100) with a seamless image as their background:

```
import {
    Scene,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    WebGLRenderer,
    TextureLoader,
    PlaneGeometry,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    Mesh,
} from 'three'
import ground from './ground.jpg'


class Game {
    private readonly scene: Scene = new Scene()
    private readonly camera: PerspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera()
    private readonly renderer: WebGLRenderer = new WebGLRenderer()

    constructor() {
        document.body.style.margin = "0"
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
        this.resizeCanvas()
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeCanvas.bind(this))
        this.setupCamera()
        this.initiateGround()
        this.render()
    }

    private initiateGround() {
        const texture = new TextureLoader().load(ground);
        const geometry = new PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
        const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});


        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                const plane = new Mesh(geometry, material);
                this.scene.add(plane);
                plane.position.set(i - 50, j - 50, 1);
            }
        }

        this.camera.position.z = 5;
        this.camera.rotation.x = .6;
    }


    private resizeCanvas(): void {
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    }


    private setupCamera() {
        this.camera.fov = 75
        this.camera.near = .001
        this.camera.far = 100
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    }


    private render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }
}

new Game()
```

For better performance, I had the idea to only show the planes that users can see. So, I searched a little bit and I found this:

```
const intersects = new Raycaster().intersectObjects(theObject);
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
     // Hidden if index > 0
}
```

But here's the problem: When I want to check if the plane is visible to user's camera, I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Mesh<PlaneGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object3D<Event>[]'.
```

Which means that I need to convert the mesh to Object3D. Although I didn't find anything in internet. So, I posted this question.

I also would really appreciate your comments on other parts of my code since it is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add `[]`:

```
const intersects = new Raycaster().intersectObjects([theObject]);
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
     // Hidden if index > 0
}
```

Comment: `intersectObjects()` expects an array of objects. But `intersectObject()` expects a single object. So you could just use the latter instead of converting to an array of one.